# Save C# Powershell as script file

Tags: c#, file, powershell

Im currently using C# to pass some objects to powershell and executing a method on them like this:

```
    var objs= new PSDataCollection<CustomObj> {obj};

    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("objList", objs);
        ps.AddScript(@"$objList| ForEach { $_.Run()}");
        ps.AddCommand("Out-String");
        var output = ps.Invoke();

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var obj in output)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }

        var result = stringBuilder.ToString().Trim();

        //Evaluate result.
    }
```

**Question:**

Is there a simply way to save my **ps** object as an script file without doing a lot of **writeline**?  I was thinking something in the lines of:

```
    ps.SaveAsScript(filename);
```

This would be a great help in a lot of my work with automation, if this is possible in a simple way.:)

Kind regards

Comment: any final solution with full source ? what is {obj} ? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not. You will have to get the commands ( `ps.Commands.Commands`) and write to a file as needed.